# system_call_after_swapgs, where is my code spending most of the time?

Tags: linux, optimization, fortran, system-calls, intel-vtune

I am trying to profile my code with intel Vtune. When looking at the function call stack it looks like most of the time is spent on a function called `system_call_after_swapgs`. However there is no stack information. My question is:
what is `system_call_after_swapgs`? And how do I know where it was called from?

[image]

Comment: It appears to be a Linux (kernel?) system function. If you in fact do not use Linux, you can remove the tag I added.

Comment: Do you have any guess about what it is doing? My feeling is that the program spends a lot of time waiting for threads  to finish due to a high load imbalance. However I can't see which part of the code is running slow.

Comment: My guess was the same. I don't know any details.

Answer (score 3):

I also see that `sysret_check` is very high. I bet if you run general exploration, then extend frontend bound/frontend latency, you'll see high % of branch resteers. If so, this is likely a performance side effects of u-code patches against Spectre attacks, that clear BTB on system calls/returns to user mode.

If this system is air-gapped, or you have other good protection measures against attacks gaining local shell, you could revert BIOS to pre-2018 versions that do not include the u-code patch.

Comment: This comment is the closest I can find to what `sysret_check` IS. Can you expand this answer at all, perhaps with references?